# Tkinter keyboard bindings not working?

Tags: python, tkinter

I threw together a very basic text editor in Python using Tkinter, but for whatever reason I can't seem to get my keyboard event bindings to work. I've checked and double-checked the documentation on using .bind() and .bind_all(), but without success. I was hoping that some fresh and definitely more experienced eyes would be able to spot the obvious error that I am sure to be missing. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ScrolledText
import tkFont
import tkFileDialog
import tkSimpleDialog
from ScrolledText import *
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from tkSimpleDialog import askstring


class SimpleTextEditor:

def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent
    self.parent.title("TextPerfect")
    self.textWidget = ScrolledText(parent, width=80, height=50, font=(tkFont.Font(family= "Consolas", size= "12")))
    self.textWidget.pack()

    self.menuBar = tk.Menu(parent, tearoff=0)
    # About Menu
    self.about_menu = tk.Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff= 0)
    self.menuBar.add_cascade(label= "TextPerfect", menu= self.about_menu)
    self.about_menu.add_command(label= "About", command= self.about_command)
    self.about_menu.add_command(label= "Quit", command= self.exit_program, accelerator="Cmd+W")
    self.about_menu.bind_all("<Command-W>", self.exit_program)

    # File Menu
    self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff = 0)
    self.menuBar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu=self.file_menu)
    self.file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.new_command, accelerator="Cmd+N")
    self.about_menu.bind_all("<Command-N>", self.dummy_funct)
    self.file_menu.add_separator()
    self.file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.open_command, accelerator="Cmd+O")
    self.file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save_command, accelerator="Cmd+S")
    self.file_menu.add_command(label="Save As...", command=self.saveAs_command, accelerator="Cmd+Shift+S")

    # Edit Menu
    self.edit_menu = tk.Menu(self.menuBar, tearoff=0)
    self.menuBar.add_cascade(label= "Edit", menu= self.edit_menu)
    self.edit_menu.add_command(label = "Cut", command = self.dummy_funct, accelerator="Cmd+X")
    self.edit_menu.add_command(label = "Copy", command = self.dummy_funct, accelerator="Cmd+C")
    self.menuBar.add_cascade(label = "Paste", menu=self.dummy_funct, accelerator="Cmd+V")

    parent.config(menu=self.menuBar)

##################################################

def open_command(self):
    file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Select a file')
    if file != None:
        contents = file.read()
        self.textWidget.insert("1.0",contents)
        file.close()

def save_command(self):
    file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode= 'w')
    if file != None:
        data = self.textWidget.get("1.0", END+'-1c')   #remove EOF new line char. from get
        file.write(data)
        file.close()

def saveAs_command(self):
    file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode= 'w')
    if file != None:
        data = self.textWidget.get("1.0", END+'-1c')   #remove EOF new line char. from get
        file.write(data)
        file.close()

def exit_program(self):
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Are you sure you want to quit?"):
        self.parent.destroy()

def new_command(self):
    print "hi"

def about_command(self):
    label = tkMessageBox.showinfo("About", "A super duper simple text editor.")                


#dummy function as a place holder while constructing further functionality        
def dummy_funct(self):
    print"The life of a function is often very lonely..."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    textApp = SimpleTextEditor(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible cause could be `<Command-N>` is interpreted differently from `<Command-n>`.
As I don't have a Mac, I changed the `Command` to `Control` and it generated an event.

If you want to stick with `<Command-N>`, then try `Command + n key` with Caps ON.

EDIT1 : Another bug with your program is, the callback methods don't correctly receive the event objects. You need to modify the signature of those methods to receive the event object.
When tk calls back, it also sends an event object containing details of the event.

Comment: Thanks for the help for generating the event. I can't believe it was something so simple as making it lowercase. In regards to your 'Edit', I'm relatively new to python programming and am not sure what you meant about modifying the signature of the methods to receive the event object.

Comment: If you are new to python/tkinter, I advice you not worry about event objects just yet. Your current code will generate an error, to fix that error, add an event argument to the callback methods like exit_program, etc by changing signature from exit_program(self) to exit_program(self, event=None). Once you are comfortable with python/tkinter, revisit these topics -> (Bindings, Events, Different argument types)

Comment: i would also suggest that rather than binding to the menu structure like you are at the moment, bind to the parent window